# Сколько способов имеется для загрузки модуля в Perl?

Tags: perl

Самый известный, и часто используемый, это:

1:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
```

Второй и третий способы, по сути аналоги `use`

2:

```
BEGIN {require LWP::UserAgent; import LWP::UserAgent;}
```

3:

```
sub BEGIN {
    require LWP::UserAgent;
    'LWP::UserAgent'->import;
}
```

А какие еще есть способы подключить модуль (если конечно есть)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если нужен `import`, то его придётся в любом случае вызвать (`Module->import/import Module`).

а вот загрузку действительно можно сделать разными способами.
основная роль `require` - найти файл, загрузить из него код и проэвалить. use - это require в BEGIN, так что добавлять при необходимости.

т.е. как-то так (с учётом пути к файлу):

```
eval( do { open my $f, "<","LWP/UserAgent.pm"; local $/; <$f> } );
LWP::UserAgent->import;
```

ещё `require` можно заменить на `do`
(но нужно учесть, что он не прописывает файл в `%INC` и он будет загружаться повторно)

```
do "LWP/UserAgent.pm";
LWP::UserAgent->import;
```

PS: ещё есть возможность перебить require:

```
*CORE::GLOBAL::require = sub {
    say "require @_";
    goto &CORE::require;
};
```

что позволяет вклиниться в процесс загрузки и что-то подменить

Comment: А для чего перебивать ``require``, и что там можно подменить, и для каких целей?

Comment: Можно полностью обрабатывать фазу загрузки модулей
Например можно сделать внешний препроцессор или source-filter, как, например, тут: https://github.com/Mons/Devel-Rewrite